# Send form to REST Controller by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, controller

I have one problem with send my form.

My form looks like:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="saveName()" modelAttribute="task" id="formName" role="form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
</form>
```

My Controller looks like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/form")
public class restController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/take", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void getFormName(@RequestParam("name") String nameTask){
        myFunction(nameTask);
    }
}
```

and I would like using Javascript to send parameters to REST. If I do it directly, using the "action" for the form, everything works. However, I would like to write a simple script that will provide all the parameters to the Controller

I tried to write a script but it did not work:

SaveName script:

```
req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', encodeURI('/form/take'), true);
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.send(encodeURI('name=' + $("#name").val()));
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Hmm, I use Ed Heal answer to my problem, but it's dosen't work.

Comment: Would you please tell what went wrong? I've tried with your code and it worked